# creating a similar "to " textbox that is displayed on many web based email websites

Tags: javascript, jquery

When we use web based email, in the `To:` text box when we add a new email address , it will be added with a small 'x' icon at right or top and we can remove that by clicking the cross icon, is there any (jQuery) plugins or plain JavaScript snippets available to accomplish such a kind of stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a look at :

http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/

and

http://webspirited.com/tagit/

Answer (score 0):

[See this demo](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) the [code is here](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput)

Sample usage:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourfiles/jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourfiles/token-input.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#my-text-input").tokenInput("/url/to/your/script/");
});
</script>
```